# Highcharts Bubble Size/Radius Animation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Finally getting back to a project to build a Highcharts based motion chart. Trying to understand if there's a way to dynamically change the radius of bubbles based on different parts of the dataset time series. The animation issue that was resolved here:

[Change in highcharts version breaks animation of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341724/change-in-highcharts-version-breaks-animation-of-elements)

Doesn't cover changing z/radius value animation. Based on the change to paths, it might not be quite as simple as changing the location. I've been looking at ScaleX and ScaleY, which would require to track the ratio to the original value for each year, but I'm hoping there's an easier way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ScaleX and ScaleY seem to throw off the positioning entirely, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your concept very well, but you should be able to achieve it by updating each point z value.

Code example:

```
chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
    p.update({
        z: p.z * Math.random() * 100
    })
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/edk184qz/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Yeah, I'm working through the process now. This approach breaks most of the previous logic which we used to employ, but may end up being the quickest way to do it! Will update.